# Monitoring incoming and outgoing trafic from browsers/skype/icq/yahoo/messenger etc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, packet-capture

I am looking to build an application that monitors all traffic from social programs like skype/icq/yahoo/messenger, that means whats being sent and whats being received. This will also later include browsing tracking, what websites are visisted and so on, and I am probably searching for a "sniffer" of somekind, but I really dont know where to start. I have read about Wireshark and Wincap that should be a .net library for doing this? But i tried that once and i got aloooot of strange text, so i was looking for a simplier way of getting the data and then filtering out the information that i need. Can anyone lead me on the right track here?

Like what program should I focus on for this kind of purpose and what can we do to filter out text that i dont want ? And will it take alot of memory/cpu doing the "sniffing" part?

Application will be built in c# .net 4.0 so the "wrapper" or sniffer must be ablet o work with c# code.

Any tips about more packet sniffers that i can read about is appreciated!
And any kind of links for me to read on or tutorials are always welcome!

Comment: Why would you need this, unless you're writing a virus?

Comment: Its not a virus for sure... Its for a it security department to analyze whats being sent in and out to be able to prevent bad data of entering and so on

Comment: Just us e a firewall then.

Comment: I am asking this because I do want to build something own , both for learning purpose and customization.....i already knew that there is something called a firewall.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/) for this. [Here](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo) is a sample showing how to use it with c#.

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += sess=>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("URL: " + sess.fullUrl);
        sess.bBufferResponse = true;
    };


Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);

Console.ReadLine();

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
```

Comment: I will defiantly check in to that! Great tips!